# how to bring exec $@ process in foreground

Tags: shell, docker, exec

I want to know how docker entry point process which has started with `exec $@` and has PID 1 how to bring that in foreground

I tried `exec $@ &` but its not working,

My use case:
I want to terminate that process once my configurations are completed, but with `exec $@` in docker entrypoint.sh my command is not getting executed since process goes in background.

Please help

Regards,
SAM

Comment: Hey Sam, maybe I am stupid and I don't understand the question right, but I don't think you gave us enough information to help you out^^

Comment: Hello Pixelbog , I apologize for that, I have one docker container which starts mongodb process with entrypoint.sh file, in that file mongodb starts with "exec $@" which leads that process runs with PID1,  and I am unable to kill it, basically i want to restart my container after mongodb process start and after my one command execution to configure some settings,  I hope you have understood 
thanks for your time

Comment: I am still a little bit confused, my bad^^ So you have a process that runs with *PID1*? Because thats a common problem in Docker. You can **not** `kill` proccesses with PID of 1, they are protected. But in case you still want to do it, you would have to add this somewhere to your `entrypoint.sh`: `trap "exit" SIGINT SIGTERM`. Is that what you want or is it something different?^^

Comment: ok if that is the only way I will use. thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah thats all I know^^ If that works, I would write an answer so you can close the quesiton. If not you can leave it open :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. There is an `--init` flag, that might work ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Process with the PID 1* is protected and simply ignores a lot of *Signals*. So it can **not** be killed with the `kill` command.

What you can do is to use the `trap` command to catch these *Signals*:

```bash
trap "exit" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

---

After some more research I have found out, that there is an `--init` flag.

The Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process